# Как передать данные из активности фрагменту(Sliding tab)

Tags: java, android

Есть код:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private String token;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    token = intent.getStringExtra("token");

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("token", token);



}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new PersonalProfileFragment(), "Персональные");
    adapter.addFragment(new QuestionaryProfileFragment(), "Анкета");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);


    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

В каком месте и как, я могу передать token в фрагмент QuestionaryProfileFragment ?

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, Bundle bundle) {
    Fragment fragment = new QuestionaryProfileFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    ...

    adapter.addFragment(fragment, "Анкета");

}
```